# Unity IAP Initialization error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am getting this error while initializing the IAP for android in unity:

> 11-02 16:15:32.621 30766-30781/? I/UnityIAP: Starting in-app billing
>   setup.
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 30766-30921/? I/UnityIAP: invoking callback
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 30766-30921/? I/UnityIAP: Checking for in-app
>   billing 3 support.
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 445-5701/? I/Finsky: [14684]
>   com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.w.b(29): (My Bundle ID): Account
>   determined from installer data - [...]
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 445-5701/? W/Finsky: [14684]
>   com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.e.a(440): Billing unavailable
>   for this package and user.
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 30766-30921/? I/UnityIAP: onIabSetupFinished: 3
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.621 30766-30921/? I/UnityIAP: Failed to setup IAB.
>   Notifying Unity...
>
> 11-02 16:15:32.631 30766-30781/? I/Unity: OnInitializeFailed
>   InitializationFailureReason:PurchasingUnavailable

I don't know this error derived from where and why it occurs! 
any idea?

Comment: It is not supported in your country or you did not setup Google Play on the Android device.

Comment: @Programmer we tested this in 2 different countries, i think its not because of my country, i install google play games on my device. should i do something else?!

Comment: You IP too. You may want to test with VPN  connected to your phone and see if that's the issue

Comment: @Programmer so how can i test IAP to see if it works properly?!

Comment: I have never used IAP and can't answer that. They have tutorials for this on their site. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/production/services-integrating-unity-ads) for their live achieve video and [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game) too for making purchases with IAP.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer, You're right, it depends on the country, I tried it with different VPNs connection, at last Brasilian VPN wprks well...

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons :
1- It is not avaiable in your country.
2- there is issue (or not configured) in Google play console.